# How to delete duplicate rows (the shorter ones) based on certain columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Suppose I have the following `df`

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, 1), col2 = c(2, 4, 2), col3 = c(NA, NA, "c"))
> df
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2 <NA>
2    3    4 <NA>
3    1    2    c
```

My goal is to delete all duplicate rows based on `col1` and `col2` such that the longer row "survives". In this case, the first row should be deleted. I tried

```
df[duplicated(df[, 1:2]), ]
```

but this gives me only the third row (and not the third and the second one). How to do it properly?

**EDIT:** The real `df` has 15 columns, of which the first 13 are used for identifying duplicates. In the last two columns roughly 2/3 of the rows are filled with NAs (the first 13 columns do not contain any NAs). Thus, my example `df` was misleading in the sense that there are two columns to be excluded for identifying the duplicates. I am sorry for that.

Comment: What if there are two rows with same `col1` and `col2` and both have non-NA `col3`? Should you keep both? Delete the first one?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this case does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort NAs to the top or bottom before dropping dupes:

```
# in base, which puts NAs last
odf = df[do.call(order, df), ]
odf[!duplicated(odf[, c("col1", "col2")]), ]

#   col1 col2 col3
# 3    1    2    c
# 2    3    4 <NA>

# or with data.table, which puts NAs first
library(data.table)
DF = setorder(data.table(df))
unique(DF, by=c("col1", "col2"), fromLast=TRUE)

#    col1 col2 col3
# 1:    1    2    c
# 2:    3    4   NA
```

This approach cannot be taken with dplyr, which doesn't offer "sort by all columns" in `arrange`, nor `fromLast` in `distinct`.

Comment: according to my new interpretation it fails with `df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, 1,3), col2 = c(2, NA, 2,4), col3 = c(NA, NA, "c",NA))` as the 2nd row of the result should be removed

Comment: @Moody Yeah, that's a possible interpretation. I'm guessing col1, col2 are grouping variables never missing; while col3+ are vectors of varying length shunted into one row each (so we see missing for any not-max-length vectors). Totally a guess, though.

Comment: @MM, your `df` is handled by Frank's `odf`-approach just the way I wanted it to. Sorry again for the ambigous exposition of the problem.

Comment: It was a fun one to think about :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>%
  slice(which.min(is.na(col3)))
```

or this :

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1,col2) %>%
  arrange(col3) %>%
  slice(1)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   col1, col2 [2]
#    col1  col2   col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fctr>
# 1     1     2      c
# 2     3     4     NA
```

**A GENERAL SOLUTION**

with the most general solution there can be only one row per value of `col1`, see comment below to add `col2` to the grouping variables. It assumes all `NAs` are on the right.

```
df %>% mutate(nna = df %>% is.na  %>% rowSums) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%         # or group_by(col1,col2)
  slice(which.min(nna)) %>%
  select(-nna)
```

Comment: Minor point: If by "longest row" OP means "I have spread a vector over many columns to the right that all look like col3", this answer will select the wrong thing with `df = data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = c(NA, "a", "a"), col4 = c(NA, NA, "b"))`. However, if the OP is really doing that, their data is in a bad format.

Comment: Hm, not necessarily. The question just has multiple interpretations that the OP perhaps ought to clarify. Looks like they've wandered off, so there's no rush in resolving it.

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, 1), col2 = c(2, 4, 2), col3 = c(NA, NA, "c"))
df <- df[order(df$col3),] 

duplicates <- duplicated(df[,1:2])
duplicates_sub <- subset(df , duplicates == FALSE)  

> duplicates_sub
  col1 col2 col3
3    1    2    c
2    3    4 <NA>
```

**EDIT:** Keep all non-NA rows

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, 1,3, 1), col2 = c(2, 4, 2,4, 2), col3 = c("a", NA, "c",NA, "b"))
df <- df[order(df$col3),] 
duplicates <- duplicated(df[,1:2]) & is.na(df[,3])
duplicates_sub <- subset(df , duplicates == FALSE)  

> duplicates_sub
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    a
5    1    2    b
3    1    2    c
2    3    4 <NA>
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper It doesn't fail for that dataframe?

Comment: you're right sorry, I executed wrong. then I don't understand the downvote

Comment: see Frank's comment on my answer, we're not general enough

Comment: Well, have a balancing upvote. My guess is that the downvoter did not like your use of `subset` instead of `df[!duplicates, ]` or more simply `df[!duplicated(df[, 1:2]), ]`.

Comment: @user108363 Sorry for the downvote (it's locked now :/). @Frank It's actually because of the fact that this would delete all subsequent duplicate rows that have different non-NA `col3`. Try this: `df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, 1,3, 1), col2 = c(2, 4, 2,4, 2), col3 = c("a", NA, "c",NA, "b"))`. I agree OP didn't state this requirement, but he/she didn't say how to deal with it either. I would cancel the downvote if OP indicates he/she doesn't care about keeping duplicates with different `col3` or that you have edited your answer to address that.

Comment: @useR thanks for the comment! I edited my code for keeping all non-NA rows.